# How to  authenticate an asp.net web app to access sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, web

I have a small web application in asp.net and I'm using SQL Server.  How do I authenticate my web application to block some people from changing the database?

This statement has to change from this:

```
Data Source=AYKUT-PC;Initial Catalog=BUS;Integrated Security=True
```

To something like this:

```
Data Source=AYKUT-PC;Initial Catalog=BUS;Integrated Security=False
```

Comment: Are all of your users going to be Windows Authenticated users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrated Security is a feature that allows SQL Server to authenticate a user based on their Windows login.

You could also use SQL Server authentication, which would require a specific user name / password to login.

Finally - you could use Mixed mode that would allow both SQL Server and Windows authentication.

Here's an article about it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx

If you would like a more detailed answer about how to implement it - you should probably give more information about your situation, and what your requirements are.

EDIT:

SQL Server can restrict permissions to users (or SQL Logins). So you could restrict acccess to certain tables through a combination of authentication methods and security permissions.